# Rails How to use model with params in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, model, pg

I want to make suggested product show up on show page I have this in my model(i am using pg)

```
//Product model
def self.similar(product_name)
        where("name LIKE ?", "%#{product_name}%").limit(4)
      end
```

How do i use this in my views(how to pass params)

Comment: What is that empty regex for?

Comment: You should use it in the controller, to assign one more instance variable, which you will use in the view. Add controller `show` action, please

Comment: SQL injection ?

Comment: `Product.similar(@product.name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure where you are getting the 'product_name' but it sounds like you just need a variable in the controller 'Show' method.

The easy way would be to just add something like the following into your Controllers 'Show' method;

```
def show
    @similar_products = Product.where("name LIKE ?", params[:product_name]).limit(4)
end
```

And then in your show page just add it into the html.erb;

```
<div class='container'>
    <% @similar_products.each do |product| %>
        <%= product.name %>
        <%= product.price %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: You missed the `%...%`

Comment: What is `@product_lines`?

Comment: on show page, I have @product.name so I want to use that  `<% @similar_products(@product.name).each do |product| %>`

Comment: You don't need to pass that @product.name as an argument. The controller takes the product_name fro the params and makes the query; `@similar_products.each` is enough.